# I am unable to use mui classes directly using className mui5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been using material ui 4 and was using makeStyles and useStyles and the code was working properly. but when i migrated to mui5 i have changed the logic to use emotion css. but the logic does not seem to work

Based on the below code i am calling the MuiSvgIcon-root class to use its properties but it shows up as blank. whereas in mui4 it works well. i think i am missing emotion css logic here. can someone please help

Note: i am not planning to override here. i just want to use as it is.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sparkling-monad-rzc7k6?file=%2Fsrc%2FStepIcon.js

Comment: In v5 of Material-UI those class names still get applied to the corresponding components so that they can be leveraged as CSS targets for customization, but the default Material-UI styles are not tied to those class names. Material-UI's default styles are applied via generated class names. You can't reuse the styles on your own components by leveraging the class names like you were with v4.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for the clarification. so i need to figure out another way to achieve this? there is no workaround for this method i guess